# NodeJS - Relative File Paths

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say have a filepath `var dir = "my/file/directory"` and I supply a relative file path `var rel = "../../other/directory/myFile.js"`, how does one compute the real directory:

```
var dir = "my/file/directory"
var rel = "../../other/directory/myFile.js"
var nDir = func(dir,rel) // returns "my/other/directory/myFile.js"
```

So far I have found `path = require('path')` and have been messing around with functions in REPL. However I cannot see where the `relative()` function, is useful in determining the final path...?

As far as I can see:

```
var p1 = "root"
var p2 = "my/dir/file.js"
var O  = path.relative(p1,p2) //returns "../my/dir/file.js"
```

it is returning the relative path... where as, to me, this should return `"root/my/dir/file.js"`?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at [Node Docs on path.resolve](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths), which returns an absolute path. `path.relative` will return a relative path.

Comment: Ah! Right. When I was looking at resolve in the console it indicated that it had no arguments!

Comment: When you type it in the node repl, it will just return what the path.resolve is, so it'll look something like [Function: resolve]. Usually when you want to check how to use a certain api, you should definitely refer to the documentation

Comment: Ah, in mine it's `function resolve() {var resolvedPath = '';var resolvedAbsolute = false;var cwd;...`. Makes sense to look in the documentation though... Just didn't think it'd be useful from what I saw.